# Likert style plot split out by levels within a factor

Tags: r, ggplot2, graphing, likert

I want to create a Likert plot which looks like this:

[image: Example Likert plot produced with the Likert package]

I have two columns in my dataframe - Age and Overall Satisfaction, both of which are factors. There is an uneven number of individuals in each age bracket. I want to produce a plot like the one above but with each bar in the plot representing a different age range. The plots above was created with the `likert` package but it doesn't seem to be able to have varying numbers of respondents.

```
df <- structure(list(Age = c("50-55 yrs", "35-40 yrs", "25-30 yrs", 
"45-50 yrs", "45-50 yrs", "20-25 yrs", "55-60 yrs", "55-60 yrs", 
"50-55 yrs", "45-50 yrs", "50-55 yrs", "55-60 yrs", "55-60 yrs", 
"65+ yrs", "60-65 yrs", "55-60 yrs", "35-40 yrs", "50-55 yrs", 
"45-50 yrs", "40-45 yrs", "45-50 yrs", "40-45 yrs", "30-35 yrs", 
"40-45 yrs", "45-50 yrs", "45-50 yrs", "30-35 yrs", "50-55 yrs", 
"40-45 yrs", "25-30 yrs"), OverallSatisfaction = c("Dissatisfied", 
"Dissatisfied", "Satisfied", "Very Dissatisfied", "Satisfied", 
"Neutral", "Dissatisfied", "Very Dissatisfied", "Very Dissatisfied", 
"Very Dissatisfied", "Very Dissatisfied", "Satisfied", "Satisfied", 
"Satisfied", "Satisfied", "Satisfied", "Neutral", "Neutral", 
"Neutral", "Neutral", "Dissatisfied", "Dissatisfied", "Dissatisfied", 
"Dissatisfied", "Dissatisfied", "Dissatisfied", "Dissatisfied", 
"Neutral", "Dissatisfied", "Neutral")), row.names = c(NA, 30L
), class = "data.frame")
```

How can I split out the bars by levels within a factor either in the `likert` package or in `ggplot2`?

I have tried the following:

```
ggplot(AgeSat.df, aes(y = OverallSatisfaction, x = Age), position = "stack") +
  geom_col(aes(fill = OverallSatisfaction)) +
  coord_flip()
```

but what I would like is to have neutrals in the center and the bottom axis (x after the coord_flip) display the percentages as in the likert example above.

Comment: Please include your attempt (not in comments) at the solution and post errors or undesird results.

Comment: Please see above :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you convert your data to a wide format, `plot.likert` has no problem plotting it even if the age groups have different sizes.

```r
library("tidyverse")
library("likert")

# Load your example data here....

ages <- sort(unique(df$Age))
satisfaction <- c("Very Dissatisfied", "Dissatisfied", "Neutral",
                  "Satisfied", "Very Satisfied")

# Commented out because it is redundant
# df$Age <- factor(df$Age, levels = ages)
df$OverallSatisfaction <- factor(df$OverallSatisfaction,
                                 levels = satisfaction)

items <- df %>%
  # Need to add an `id` column or `tidyr::spread` will complain.
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>%
  spread(Age, OverallSatisfaction) %>%
  # Need to remove `id` column or `likert::likert` will complain.
  select(-id)

plot(likert(items), type = "bar")

# If you want to specify how to sort the age groups
plot(likert(items), type = "bar", group.order = ages)
# or
plot(likert(items), type = "bar", group.order = rev(ages))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-03-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: Thank you for the helpful answer! How can I correct the y-axis to display the age brackets in ascending or descending order?

Comment: You can specify the item order (here the items are the age groups) with the `group.order` of the `plot.likert` function.

Comment: Very nice @dipetkov and much easier than my clumsy approach. +1

Answer (score 2):

Here is a somewhat "hacky" approach that boils down to reformatting your data in a way that it resembles a `likert` object, and then using `plot.likert` to plot.

```
library(tidyverse)
res <- df %>%
    group_by(Age, OverallSatisfaction) %>%
    tally() %>%
    group_by(Age) %>%
    transmute(
        OverallSatisfaction,
        frac = n / sum(n) * 100) %>%
    spread(OverallSatisfaction, frac, fill = 0) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    mutate(Age = factor(Age)) %>%
    rename(Item = Age) %>%
    as.data.frame()
items <- df %>%
    group_by(Age) %>%
    mutate(n = 1:n()) %>%
    spread(Age, OverallSatisfaction) %>%
    select(-n) %>%
    mutate_all(~factor(., levels = levels(factor(df$OverallSatisfaction)))) %>%
    as.data.frame()

# Manually construct likert object from res and items
library(likert)
data <- list(
    results = res,
    items = items,
    nlevels = length(names(res)[-1]),
    levels = names(res)[-1])
class(data) <- "likert"

# Plot using plot.likert
plot(data)
```

[image]

We can compare results with those from a simple `table` call

```
table(df$Age, df$OverallSatisfaction)
#          Dissatisfied Neutral Satisfied Very Dissatisfied
#20-25 yrs            0       1         0                 0
#25-30 yrs            0       1         1                 0
#30-35 yrs            2       0         0                 0
#35-40 yrs            1       1         0                 0
#40-45 yrs            3       1         0                 0
#45-50 yrs            3       1         1                 2
#50-55 yrs            1       2         0                 2
#55-60 yrs            1       0         3                 1
#60-65 yrs            0       0         1                 0
#65+ yrs              0       0         1                 0
```

Comment: Thank you for the helpful answer! How can I correct the y-axis to display the age brackets in ascending or descending order?